# how to update value with several conditions

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following table:

```
id - phone - value
1  - 1234  - null
2  - 4321  - null
3  - 1234  - null
```

I need to update "value" column with phone "1234" with max(id)

```
id - phone - value
1  - 1234  - null
2  - 4321  - null
3  - 1234  - *updated
```

I tried to do this lots of times with the following queries:

`cur.execute("UPDATE online_booking SET st1 = (%s) HAVING max(ID) and phone = (%s)", (st1, phone))`

but it says "syntax error at or near "HAVING""

Answer (score 1):

You should filter `id` by a subquery like this:

```
UPDATE online_booking 
SET st1 = '*update' 
WHERE id = (
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM online_booking
    WHERE phone = '1234')
```

Answer (score 0):

HAVING can be used only if you used GROUP BY before.

You're looking for something like

`UPDATE online_booking SET st1 = (%s) WHERE phone = (%s) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1`

This query will update only 1st row.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to update the cell with maximum ID number